# How to call ajax by clicking d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, d3.js

I want to call an ajax function to send data from my graph (d3.js forced layout graph) to a controller action in rails.

My graph is created from json (from the classic miserables example). I want to allow a user to click on a node and for that to trigger an ajax 'GET' call to an action in rails.

The controller is called users and the action is show
I want to send the name of the node back to the show action

So far I have:

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("click",  getprofile(d.name));}) 
      .on('dblclick', connectedNodes);


function getprofile(){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/users/show" ,
})
};
```

Obviously this doesn't work. I'm not really sure how to pass the name of the node to ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to all your variables, but I ran a stripped down version and this seems to work. I changed your line:

```
.on("click",  getprofile(d.name));})
```

to

```
.on("click",  function(d) { getprofile(d.name); })
```

and I don't know where in the ajax call you were planning on plugging the name variable in, but this:

```
function getprofile(name){
    console.log(name);
};
```

Will console.log your d.name from your node.  You can just use that name var to plug in to wherever you need it in your AJAX call.  Hope that helps.

Comment: OK so in the ajax call can I write something like data : { name: JSON.stringify(d.name) }       I am trying to pass this over to the controller so that I can access the data by params[:name]

Comment: I don't think you want to put the JSON.stringify inside the object, don't you want to do something like `data: JSON.stringify({name: name})` instead?  Or if your AJAX contentType is already set to "application/json", then just `{name: name}` I think.  Also you don't need the "d.", inside getprofile - the function (as I wrote it) expects the argument to just be called 'name'.

Comment: Great answer thanks. Sorted. Now I've just got to sort the controller out.